# des file encryption corrupts file

Tags: vb.net, encryption, des

i have written a class in vb.net to encrypt/decrypt files, but when i decrypt files like images or zips or office files, they look corrupted. But if i open the decrypted and original file in notepad they are exactly the same. What can i do to stop this?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Encrytion
Shared Sub EncryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sOutputFilename As String, ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()

    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                        desencrypt, _
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)


    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    cryptostream.Close()
End Sub

Shared Sub DecryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sOutputFilename As String, ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    Dim fsread As New FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim desdecrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor()

    Dim cryptostreamDecr As New CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

    Dim fsDecrypted As New StreamWriter(sOutputFilename)
    fsDecrypted.Write(New StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd)
    fsDecrypted.Flush()
    fsDecrypted.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `But if i open the decrypted and encrypted file in notepad they are exactly the same.` - how this could be possible?

Comment: First thought: Remember to set the file suffix back to its previous suffix. i.e. .txt .zip .whatever.

Comment: @WozzeC i always set the file suffix back to the original one

Comment: Code looks okay, how are you calling these methods? Are you passing in the same file names?

Comment: @Ameen this is my test project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qke1pplvia4gudb/AO5VhizAAf

Comment: @kasperB Your code works fine. The dropbox thing compiles and runs OK. I can encrypt and decrypt without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057010/493055) to solve this problem.  In short, the Encrypt and Decrypt functions should be exactly the same, outside of the `CreateEncryptor`/`CreateDecryptor` calls:

```
Shared Sub EncryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sOutputFilename As String, ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor(DES.Key, DES.IV)

    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                        desencrypt, _
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)


    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    cryptostream.Flush()

    cryptostream.Close()
End Sub

Shared Sub DecryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sOutputFilename As String, ByVal sKey As String)
    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor(DES.Key, DES.IV)

    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                        desencrypt, _
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)


    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    cryptostream.Flush()

    cryptostream.Close()
End Sub
```